# Is Ubuntu Better In Dual Boot or VMWare?

Tags: vmware

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu. I would like to install Ubuntu on a computer that runs Windows XP. My question is to know whether dual boot is better than VMware. Also I just found out that there is VMware and VMBoot? Can anybody explain the difference to me and which one is better?

Thank you,
Simon

Answer (score 1):

A VM is easer to play around with and can be quicker to set up because you do not need to find all divers and if you make any mistakes, and everyone does, it is a lot  easer to clean-up after. There are benefits to Dual Booting however, with the big one, for me at least, is that you have access to all the RAM of your computer. As Pilot6 has said it does run slower and does not have all the capabilities in any VM. Look at your options and chose based on your needs and general computer knowledge.

I personally have not VMboot so I can not tell you the difference.

As for witch one is "better"  I can not say because that is an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem to answer is that who knows the criterion of "being better"?

If you install Ubuntu in as a virtual machine, it will not use all capabilities of your computer and will work sufficiently slower.

But the installation may be easier and you wont't need to worry about drivers in some cases.

I vote to close as opinion based.