# Which is best either dual boot or virtualization for working with neural networks?

Tags: dual-boot, vmware

I wish to learn and work on neural networks and deep learning. I have an MSI Apache Pro laptop with 1TB HDD and 256GB SSD, with an nVidia GTX 1060 graphics card. I am afraid that dual boot may have problems with graphics driver and also afraid that virtualization may not be so effective and I may not be able to use my system efficiently.
What shall I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Ubuntu Better In Dual Boot or VMWare?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653864/is-ubuntu-better-in-dual-boot-or-vmware)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dual boot will perform a lot better, and as you are running heavy loads you will not want to have the extra overhead of virtualisation.

To test your graphics you can use a Live USB to see if it works straight away, or if you will need to install drivers.

Instructions on how to make a Live USB can be found [here](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0)